# how to gracefully kill linux perf tool process

Tags: linux, performance-monitoring, perf

I'm trying to use the linux performance tool `perf` to monitor kvm events on a host where a guest VM exists.

The command I invoke `perf` is

```sh
perf kvm stat record
```

After some time, I'll press `Ctrl + C` to stop it and it will show some info like how many times it has been waken up to write data, and it will spend some time before truly exiting, which I suppose it's writing data.

Basically what I want to achieve is automatically stop the `perf` process after 1 minute. Here is a prototype of my script:

```sh
perf kvm stat record &
pid=$!
sleep 60
sudo kill -2 $pid
```

The problem here is when I terminate the process in this way, it won't properly write data to disk.And I've tried to send signal `2` and `9`, neither works for me.

Does anyone know how to properly interrupt `perf` process so that it will finish writing data then exit?

Comment: Have you tried **kill -15 <pid>** (SIGTERM (15)) ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the perf kvm description [here](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Perf_events), you have to use SIGINT(7) to kill the perf process. This ensures that perf properly dumps the collected data to file.

```
perf kvm stat record &
pid=$!
sleep 60
sudo kill -INT $pid
```